# Restrict node with CAPTCHA

Tags: drupal, captcha

is there any quick solution to restrict access to one node (page) with a captcha module (or some other, similar way)?

Comment: CAPTCHAs are only designed to make it difficult for bots to get access. If you want to restrict access to a page you should consider for example a username and password. What is your use case? Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Well, i'm creating some simple website for a customer, and he wants to protect a search engine from bots - everyone else should be able to access it, so i thought captcha will do the trick.. ;)

Comment: If the purpose is to block some search engine bots, then CAPTCHAs is not the solution I would adopt; this would bother normal users. I would rather check the user agent, even if it is not 100% sure; the pro is that users would not need to enter anything before to see content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to allow a user to access a node if he passes a CAPTCHA, then there isn't any module for that.
If I understood what you mean, the module should present a CAPTCHA, and if the answer is correct, then the node should be shown.
You can create a custom module using the CAPTCHA module.

Comment: That's exactly what im looking for.. Argh not good, i wish writing custom module wasn't necessary ;)

Comment: I would suggest to create a custom module; this would avoid to use PHP filter in nodes content, or to <code>eval()</code> PHP code. In example, on drupal.org the PHP input format is never used, and the dynamic content generated for some pages is handled by a module of [Drupal.org customizations](http://drupal.org/project/drupalorg). There is always some customization required from a site that needs custom code; a custom module is, IMO, the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to block bots, try these:

- [ddos](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ddos)
- [botbouncer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbouncer)

I have used **"ddos"** earlier just to block too many requests from an IP on a previous website. The usage is fairly simple: -

In your app.js, add

```
var Ddos = require('ddos')
var ddos = new Ddos({burst:10, limit:50,errormessage:'Maximum number of 
requests exceeded from your system, please wait to regain access'})

app.use(ddos.express);
```

So, how ddos works is it maintains an internal count of the number of requests it receives from each IP. For every request it receives, it increments the counter. And for every second that passes without a request, the previous entries are deleted.

Now, if for a certain IP, the limit (here, 50) is exceeded, 429 error is thrown. From here on in, every subsequent request increments at the specified **burst** rate (here, 10) until the internal counter resets.

This is the next best thing to incorporating Cloudflare on your website. Hope that helps!